Binding with Datagid is not working all times after adding more code lines
I can Bind an observablelist to datagrid in WPF, but I am losing Binding when adding a custom filtering functionality to Datagrid
I created a User Control which contains a DataGrid in WPF, the DataGrid is bound to variable "FilteredCollection"
        public ObservableCollection<cs_Log> FilteredCollection
        {
            get { return _filteredcollection; }
            set { _filteredcollection = value; OnPropertyChanged("FilteredCollection"); dgLogger.ItemsSource = _filteredcollection; }
        }

When I call the following function, the data is copied and datagrid is showing the new added rows correctly
        void ApplyFilter()
        {
            FilteredCollection = csGlobal.LogList;
        }

later I added a checkbox for filtering and I bound it to variable "InfoInclude", also I modified the function
        public bool InfoInclude
        {
            get { return _infoinclude; }
            set { _infoinclude = value; OnPropertyChanged("InfoInclude"); ApplyFilter(); }
        }


        void ApplyFilter()
        {
            ObservableCollection<cs_Log> TempCollection = new ObservableCollection<cs_Log>();
            foreach (cs_Log item in csGlobal.LogList)
                if (((item.sType == "Information") && InfoInclude) || ((item.sType == "Warning") && WarnInclude) || ((item.sType == "Error") && ErrInclude))
                    TempCollection.Add(item);
            FilteredCollection = TempCollection;
            //FilteredCollection = csGlobal.LogList;
        }

the result was:

When adding a new rows the "FilteredCollection" variable is already updated but the datagrid is not showing the new added rows
the when checking/unchecking the checkbox, the datagrid show the filtered data on the datagrid

How can I have both adding and filtering functionality to work together as same time?
Thanks

Replacing the instance of ObservableCollection with new one will break the binding. Instead, update the items of the existing ObservableCollection.

What do you call binding? Is it by any chance this code fragment dgLogger.ItemsSource = _filteredcollection;? If so, you are scaring me (irony). In general, your answer lacks implementation details. The explanations you provided are insufficient, since according to them (if they are understood as is accepted in the developer community), everything is done correctly and should work correctly.

@emoacht
In this implementation, replacing an ObservableCollection instance cannot break the binding or prevent it from working.
But there are serious doubts that this is really a Binding.

@EldHasp You are right. I missed it.

From your explanations I understood: the FilteredCollection collection is loaded with a full collection of rows when the view starts; the InfoInclude, WarnInclude, ErrInclude properties are created only to manage filtering. If this is correct, then in my opinion, a more optimal implementation of filtering would be at the View level.
Look at this example (the code you didn't show, I'm recreating it based on my guesses):
    public class LogViewModel
    {
        private GlobalModel csGlobal = new();

        public LogViewModel()
        {
            FilteredCollection = new(csGlobal.LogList);
        }

        public ObservableCollection<cs_Log> FilteredCollection { get; }

    }

Window XAML:
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:LogViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <UniformGrid Columns="2">
        <DataGrid x:Name="dgLog" Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredCollection}"/>
        <UniformGrid Columns="1">
            <CheckBox x:Name="InfoInclude"
                      Content="{Binding Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                      Click="OnRefreshFilter"
                      VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            <CheckBox x:Name="WarnInclude"
                      Content="{Binding Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                      Click="OnRefreshFilter"
                      VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            <CheckBox x:Name="ErrInclude"
                      Content="{Binding Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                      Click="OnRefreshFilter"
                      VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        </UniformGrid>
    </UniformGrid>
</Window>

Window Code Behind:
        private void OnRefreshFilter(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            bool infoInclude = InfoInclude.IsChecked == true;
            bool warnInclude = WarnInclude.IsChecked == true;
            bool errInclude = ErrInclude.IsChecked == true;

            dgLog.Items.Filter = item =>
            {
                cs_Log log = (cs_Log)item;

                return log.sType switch
                {
                    "Information" => infoInclude,
                    "Warning" => warnInclude,
                    "Error" => errInclude,
                    _ => false
                };
            };
        }

P.S. And please note that binding is not just a "nice term", but an instance of Binding set, in this case, in the value of a property in XAML.
